# Using Jaxb2Marshaller to unmarshall an xml and validate against a schema

Tags: spring, jaxb2

I am implementing a REST service with xml as the payload and have the following configuration to use Jaxb2Marshaller to unmarshall my xml. Here is the configuration from my spring context file

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.my.examples.Product</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="schema" value="classpath:schemadefinitions/product.xsd" />
    </bean>
```

On my bean **Product** I have just this annotation as

@XmlRootElement(name="product")
public class ProductInfo {

The issue is when I make the REST request it unmarshalls xml to bean properly but doesn't perform any validation against the schema configured with the marshaller. Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to attach a validationeventhandler to the marshaller as jaxb2Mashaller.setValidationEventHandler(...) Once this is set the unmarshaller started to validate input xml.

Comment: I added validationeventhandler also. But not validating :(

Comment: @SelvaG the flagged "flagged as correct answer" is not correct. If you programmatically create your Jaxb2Marshaller, make sure to call afterPropertiesSet, since this an InitializingBean.

Answer (score 1):

With **Java 8 and JaxB 2.2.4**, I don't see any problems with the original setup! Defining the schema property in the *applicationcontext.xml* is **ALL** you need to do in order to get schema validation going.

If one creates `Jaxb2Marshaller` "manually", one needs to make sure to call the `afterPropertiesSet` method after setting the schema resource, since it loads the schema resource into memory.